# How to use renderPrint to display actual variable names when dynamically selecting inputs with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Say I have the following simple app (.Rmd):

````
---
title: "Simple LM"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
checkboxGroupInput(
  "vars", label = "Select Variable(s)", 
  choices = names(mtcars), selected = "cyl", inline = TRUE
)

# This looks nice
renderPrint({
  reformulate(input$vars, "mpg")
})

# This doesn't look great
renderPrint({
  lm(reformulate(input$vars, "mpg"), data = mtcars)
})
```
````

[image: Simple App]

Is it possible to have `renderPrint()` for the call to `lm()` use the *actual* variable names?

Current: `lm(formula = reformulate(input$vars, "mpg"), data = mtcars)`
Desired: `lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)`

I have tried using `as.formula(paste0(...))` but the results are similar.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hacky, but you could overwrite the call variable of your lm output:

```
  linM <- lm(reformulate(input$vars, "mpg"), data = mtcars)
  linM$call <- reformulate(input$vars, "mpg")
```

Reproducible example reads:

````
---
title: "Simple LM"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
checkboxGroupInput(
  "vars", label = "Select Variable(s)", 
  choices = names(mtcars), selected = "cyl", inline = TRUE
)

renderPrint({
  linM <- lm(reformulate(input$vars, "mpg"), data = mtcars)
  linM$call <- reformulate(input$vars, "mpg")
  linM
})
```
````

Comment: Thanks +1 -- agree, feels like a hack and going to leave this unanswered for a bit to see if others have ideas. Care to elaborate on what's going on here?

Comment: I would be also interested if there is a different solution. Well if you open the source code of the lm function, you see how they assign the formula the call variable. Not sure why it is done that way,...